# Pandas rename column based on column to the left

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe, `df`:

```
Metric_a Status.1 Metric_b Status.2, Metric_c, Status.3
10       kg       11       mg        15        ml
12       kg       21       mg        25        ml
130      kg       41       mg        35        ml
```

I read this in from a `csv` which uses multiple `Status` columns. Pandas naturally index's these.

I wish to use the column to the left of each `Status` column to rename the `Status` column. From inspection I believe that order is maintained and that the column to the left is always appropriate.

Desired output:

```
Metric_a Status_Metric_a Metric_b Status_Metric_b Metric_c, Status_Metric_c
    10       kg       11       mg        15        ml
    12       kg       21       mg        25        ml
    130      kg       41       mg        35        ml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) (it works only with `Series`, so is necessary convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html)):

```
a = df.columns.to_series()
mask = a.str.contains('Status')
df.columns = a.mask(mask, 'Status_' + a.mask(mask).ffill())
print (df)
   Metric_a Status_Metric_a  Metric_b Status_Metric_b  Metric_c  \
0        10              kg        11              mg        15   
1        12              kg        21              mg        25   
2       130              kg        41              mg        35   

  Status_Metric_c  
0              ml  
1              ml  
2              ml
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
a = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = np.where(a.str.contains('Status'), 'Status_' + a.shift(), a)
print (df)
   Metric_a Status_Metric_a  Metric_b Status_Metric_b  Metric_c  \
0        10              kg        11              mg        15   
1        12              kg        21              mg        25   
2       130              kg        41              mg        35   

  Status_Metric_c  
0              ml  
1              ml  
2              ml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename` method pandas provide.
For example :

```
df.rename(columns={'Status.1': 'Status_Metric_a'}, inplace=True)
```